# How do insert HTML into word document?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a webpart . I insert InputFormTextBox into webpart.

I want save InputFormTextBox.text into word file with formating.

How do insert HTML into word document?

Comment: Are you looking for a docx or doc format? The OpenXML SDK and will help you inserting text into docx documents. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx might be good places to start.

Comment: Thanks , I am looking for a docx format.Can I use another method other than OpenXML SDK ؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The altChunk markup tells the consuming application to import content into the document.

I use this code:

```
 XNamespace w =
      "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
    XNamespace r =
        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships";
    File.Copy("E:\\Test.docx", "E:\\Test3.docx");
    using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
       WordprocessingDocument.Open("E:\\Test3.docx", true))
    {
        string html =
          @"<html>
        <head/>
        <body>
           <p>        To<em> learn</em> more a<em>bout<strong> </strong> </em><strong>ASP.</strong>NET vi<span >sit jh kj</span> h</p> <strong>,j jlkjlj;lk;</strong>
        </body>
    </html>";
        string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
            "application/xhtml+xml", altChunkId);
        using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))
            stringStream.Write(html);
        XElement altChunk = new XElement(w + "altChunk",
            new XAttribute(r + "id", altChunkId)
        );
        XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = GetXDocument(myDoc);
        mainDocumentXDoc.Root
            .Element(w + "body")
            .Elements(w + "p")
            .Last()
            .AddAfterSelf(altChunk);
        SaveXDocument(myDoc, mainDocumentXDoc);
    }


    private static void SaveXDocument(WordprocessingDocument myDoc, XDocument mainDocumentXDoc)
{
    // Serialize the XDocument back into the part
    using (Stream str = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(str))
        mainDocumentXDoc.Save(xw);
}
private static XDocument GetXDocument(WordprocessingDocument myDoc)
{
    // Load the main document part into an XDocument
    XDocument mainDocumentXDoc;
    using (Stream str = myDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream())
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(str))
        mainDocumentXDoc = XDocument.Load(xr);
    return mainDocumentXDoc;
}
```